# How do I set the dart2js --minify option from the command line when executing `pub build`?

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, dart-pub, dart2js

For my release process I need several different "modes." However, if I use the `--mode` option for `pub build` and set it to any value other than `release`, it forces *un*-minified javascript.

I know I can configure the dart2js transformer in my `pubspec.yaml`, but if I set `minify: true` under the `$dart2js` heading in my `pubspec.yaml` I am then forcing them to be minified, and then cannot produce un-minified debug builds.

What I'm really looking for is a way to configure arbitrary dart2js options (minified, checked, etc.) in `pub build` via the CLI (so that I don't have to hardcode in `pubspec.yaml`), or, failing that, to be able to specify additional arbitrary flags from the `pub build` CLI so that I can reserve `--mode` for `debug` and `release`. The `asPlugin()` transformer constructor takes a `BarbackSettings` object, but I can't see how to see arbitrary params in that **via the command line**.

Comment: I think you're asking about this issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19569

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anything like that mentioned (for example in any of the bug reports) and I'm pretty sure this is not supported. I suggest to just create a feature request at http://dartbug.com.

One way I can think of is to create a script which manipulates the `pubspec.yaml` file before executing `pub build`. This should be easy using the https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yaml package.